# What is the term for ACC + antichain free?

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, order-theory

Given a partial set $(A, \leq)$, ascending chain condition (ACC) means that there is no infinite strictly ascending chain. Meanwhile, no infinite antichain is also a common condition on $A$.

I am wondering whether there is a standard term for $A$ to state that it satisfies ACC and antichain free.

Comment: How about "inversely well ordered"?

Comment: "well co-ordered"? "co-wellordered"? None of these are real I'm just talking.

Comment: This has also been called a dual well partial order.

Comment: I am not sure whether this is correct, but can I say that $(A, \geq)$ is a well partial order?

Comment: "Well partial orders" and "dual well partial orders" can have antichains of more than one element.